# Homomorphism from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ where it is the identity on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: ring-theory

I'm trying to find all homomorphisms from the ring $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ such that it is the identity on $\mathbb{R}$.

So I know that:

- $f(w+z) = f(w) + f(z)$
- $f(wz) = f(w)f(z)$
- $f(1) = 1$

and also that

- $f(x) = x$ whenever $x$ is real.

Can I then deduce from this that $f(x+iy) = f(x)+if(y)$ and so then $f(z) = z$?

I'm quite stuck here and would appreciate some pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Hint: Consider the image of $i$, since that will determine the image of the rest of $\mathbb{C}$.  Is there any other element that satisfies $x^2+1=0$?

Comment: So if $i$ is the solution to $x^2 + 1 = 0$ then $f(x^2 + 1) = f(0) = 0$ and so $f(x)^2 = -f(1) = -1$ and then we can deduce $f(x) = i$ so $f(i) = i$? and so the only map is the identity?

Comment: $i$ is not the only solution to $x^2+1$.  Note that it factors as $(x+i)(x-i)$.

Comment: So we have that $f(i) = ± i$, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That deduction cannot be made because the complex conjugaison is a homomorphism.